# most elegant way to get benefits of map and filter in javascript for reducing array and changing variables within it

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I've found a couple of ways to remove a set of values from an array, and then change the values within the array (or in reverse order). For example:

```
original_array= ["unwanted variable 1","Score: Question 1","Score: Question 2","Score: Question 3","unwanted variable 2"];
// i want to end with just the "Score:" variables.
// method 1 
scales = original_array.filter(function(element){
       if(element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1){
           return element.replace("Score: ","");
       } 
    });
```

I was hoping that this would both reduce the array down to the relevant variables, and replace the "Score: " with nothing. It reduces the array, but doesn't change the value of the variables.

I've also tried using .map instead of .filter.

```
  //method 2
  scales = original_array.map(function(element){
       if(element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1){
           return element.replace("Score: ","");
       } 
    });
```

Which replaces all the invalid variables with "undefined", but does change the value of the valid variables (e.g. "Question 1" rather than "Score: Question 1".

Is there an elegant way to make use of either of these functions to both filter and then rename the variables? Or do I have to this in two steps?

Comment: `.filter(/,/.test, /^Score/).map(x=>x.slice(7))` is simpler than combining...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `filter` and `map` you can use `reduce`, here is an example:

```js
var original_array= ["unwanted variable 1","Score: Question 1","Score: Question 2","Score: Question 3","unwanted variable 2"];
var scales = original_array.reduce(function(acc, element){
       if(element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1){
           acc.push(element.replace("Score: ",""));
       } 
       return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(scales)
```

What this does is to check if the element meets the criteria `element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1` and adds the modified element to the returned array (`acc.push(....)`).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst writing the question I found that you can combine .map and .filter:

```
scales = original_array.filter(function(element){
     if(element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1){
         return element;
     } 
}).map(function(element){ 
     return element.replace("Score: ","");
});
```

However - I'm hoping there's an easier or more elegant solution than this.

Comment: just slightly, with ES6: `scales = original_array.filter(elm => elm.includes("Score:")).map(elm => elm.replace("Score: ",""));`. There's no need to return your `element` in the fitlter function. It takes any truthy/falsy value to determine wether to add the element to the result, or not.

Answer (score 0):

While you have an answer of yourself, you might get the right way for filtering an array, because you return an element, but [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) need a truthy value, which can be the result of checking itself.

```
scales = original_array.filter(function(element) {
    return element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1;      // just return the result of checking
}).map(function(element) { 
    return element.replace("Score: ", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> It reduces the array, but doesn't change the value of the variables

`Array.filter` as name implies, filters the array. It expects a callback that should return boolean value. If true, value will be returned. If false, value will be ignored.

> Which replaces all the invalid variables with "undefined", but does change the value of the valid variables (e.g. "Question 1" rather than "Score: Question 1".

`Array.map` as name implies, maps some value to existing values in array. That means, it will create a temp array and put return value of callback on the current index position. If you do not return anything, by default, it will set that index to `undefined`.

---

If you wish to do both, you have methods like `Array.forEach` and `Array.reduce`.

The use of `Array.reduce` is depicted in @[Titus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552587/titus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543258/3783478).

Following is the implementation on `Array.forEach`.

```js
var original_array = ["unwanted variable 1", "Score: Question 1", "Score: Question 2", "Score: Question 3", "unwanted variable 2"];
var scales = [];
original_array.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.indexOf("Score:") !== -1) {
    scales.push(element.replace("Score: ", ""));
  }
});

console.log(scales)
```